# How to connect C-Wire to Weil-McLain Boiler CGa Series 3

Tags: wiring, thermostat, water-heater, thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I'm trying to install a Nest learning WIFI thermostat to my boiler. However, I'm not sure where to connect the common wire. I've went through multiple posts on this forum but unfortunately wasn't able to find a resolution.

Below is my boiler's schematic wiring diagram. [Diagram Link](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/egh-control-supplement-universal-control-systems_1.pdf)
[image: Schematic wiring diagram]

**I'm assuming that TSTAT BK(C) is the common wire?** However, my boiler is connected to low water cut off and high water limit. In attached picture, blue pen drawing shows existing wirings. The Low Water Cut Off has 4 wires, and one is already connected to the C Common terminal. Can I just connect my thermostat’s C wire to the same terminal? (Green pen in drawing) Thanks!

Also, please let me know if the wiring is correct because the previous owner installed the boiler himself so the wiring might be off.

[image: Diagram Drawing]

[image: Updated Diagram]

[image: Second Boiler]

[image: Low Water Cut Off]

[image: Aquastat]

[image: nameplate]

[image: boiler picture]

Comment: Is your boiler providing *hot water* to your heating system, or *steam*?

Comment: It's providing hot water to the heating system. Thanks for the question

Comment: Can you post photos of your boiler's nameplate please?

Comment: Just added a few more pictures to the thread. Let me know if you need additional information!

Comment: the manual for your boiler can be found [here](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/CGa%20Series%203%20Boiler%20Manual%20%20%200520.pdf) (it's a CGa Series 3, not the EG/PEG that other posters here had)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You'll need to work around what the installer did

Your boiler's installer put the safeties (high limit aquastat, LWCO) in line with the thermostat instead of wiring them in with the spill switch as the [CGa manual](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/CGa%20Series%203%20Boiler%20Manual%20%20%200520.pdf#page=37) calls for.  As a result of this, you'll need to tie the green wire into the R wire from the transformer and control connector, then connect it to Rc on your Nest, in addition to connecting the blue wire to C as you indicate in your diagram.  The red wire then lands on Rh, with the white on W, as you'd expect; this means that your boiler won't confuse your thermostat if it ever malfunctions and cuts out on low water, overtemperature, or such.

Comment: I've added a new digram with dash lines following what you recommended. Hopefully this is what you meant. where is R wire from the control board? Just curious, why do we need to connect green wire to red transformer and also connect it to Rc?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- to make sure the thermostat doesn't get confused by a power cut if the low-water cutoff or high-limit aquastat kicks in to shut the boiler down

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- yeah, your diagram looks correct

Comment: I added a new diagram for my second boiler. However, I noticed the wiring is very different than the first one. Can I still use the suggestion above with the dash lines?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- swap the wires going to RH and W on the thermostat, and you should be good for Boiler #2

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mind clarify why do we need to swap RH and W for the second boiler (the new flow will be Red wire going to W and White wire going to Rh)? Isn't red wire usually means Rh, and White wire is W? Did the previous installer mess it up?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- it's not strictly necessary to swap them, no

Comment: I just connected thermostat c wire to black common wire from boiler, the smart thermostat is lighting up and showing the temperature. However, when I set the temperature, it's not heating up? Do you know why? I didn't swap Rh with W, do I need to swap these two wires?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- make sure you have Rc provided as well as Rh

Comment: Just connected Rc to Red transformer. The boiler automatically starts heating, and I can't turn it off or set a temperature? hmmm

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- that's weird, you may have to go and reinit system setup on that Nest to make it "see" that it has separate power on Rc and Rh

Comment: do you think it's because my second boiler wiring is wrong? should I switch the wires to make them look like the first boiler? Thermostat Rh to LWCO white, Thermostat W to TSTAT black, LWCO yellow to Aquastat white, LWCO white to TSTAT common.

Comment: Also the thermostat already has a jumper wire between Rh and Rc, should I cut the jumper wire?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- aah, I thought the second thermostat was a Nest as well -- since it's some other sort of thermostat with a physical Rh-Rc jumper, you'll have to remove the jumper wire

Comment: got it, I'll cut the jumper wire.. I also noticed that current w wire has voltage and r wire doesn't at thermostat. Shouldn't r be the wire with power and w without any voltage? should I swap them, maybe the previous installer didn't follow the color coding?

Comment: it worked!! thank you. After trying to install it for three months, my new home finally has a smart thermostat installed! Do you mind explain again why we need to connect Rc to Red transformer? Also why if not connected, I can't set the heat from the thermostat? Also if not cut the jumper wire from the thermostat, the heat will always be on and can't turn off?

Comment: @Kevin2344 -- the issue with the jumper was that it was shorting R to W effectively (and cutting out safeties in the process).  Connecting Rc to the transformer is needed so that a safety trip doesn't cut power to the thermostat entirely and confuse it